# Want to create Custom Header based on Geo Location

Tags: custom-header

I am having 2 header UK & US Header. I want to redirect the US header & footer based on US location.

I am using Geo Redirection Plugin, but by using this plugin i can modifiy the URL redirection, not able to change the header.

So please help to redirect the based on GEO Redirects

Thank you